# Sequence of subspace and their continuous linear functional

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a complex Hibert space

Let $S_n$ be a sequence of subsets of $H$ such that for each $n \in \mathbb N$:
$S_n$ is compact, $S_{n+1}\subsetneq S_n$, $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty S_n=\{v_0\}$, $S_n$ is linear independent

Let, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, be $V_n= \overline{span(S_n)}$ and $T_n:V_n\to\mathbb C$ continuous linear functional such that $T_n(v_0)=0$

My question is if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert T_n \rVert = 0$

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you want the $S_n$ to be linear independent sets? Otherwise $H=\mathbb C$ and $S_n=\{1/N\mid N>n\}\cup\{0\}$. So $V_n=\mathbb C=H$ for all $n$ and $T_n$ does not change.

Comment: Yes, @s.harp, $S_n$ are linear independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $H := \ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and $S_n := \{e_1\}\cup \{e_1+\frac{1}{j}e_j:~j\geq n+1\}$, where $\{e_i: i\in\mathbb N\}$ is the standard base of $\ell^2$. Then $S_n$ is compact for each $n$, $\bigcap S_n = \{e_1\}$ and $$V_n = \{(x_1,x_2,...)\in \ell^2\vert~ \forall j\in\{2,...,n\}:\quad x_j=0\}.$$

Let $T_n:V_n\to\mathbb C,x\mapsto x_{n+1}$. Then obviously $\|T_n\| = 1$ for each $n$ and $T_n(e_1) = 0$ for each $n$.

Comment: ok @LeBtz, thanks so much.

Comment: exuse me @LeBtz why $||T_n||=1$ ?

Comment: Because $e_{n+1}\in V_n$

Comment: ok @LeBtz thanks you are kind